# How to visualize relationships in text on a web

Tags: data-visualization, text-mining

I would like to implement a webpage that would present text, color and mark entities and draw lines between entities that are linked. Something like Brat annotation tool does (but with no editing). If one has offsets of entities and list of entities that are related, how can this be done?